# Get request body string from Play's GlobalSettings.onBadRequest

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

In my Play-Scala application I need to log bad requests from the clients. To do this, I overrode `GlobalSettings.onBadRequest` as follows:

```
override def onBadRequest(request: RequestHeader, error: String) = {
  L.warn(s"Bad request: $request! Error: $error")
  Future.successful(Results.BadRequest)
}
```

However, I cannot access the request body (i.e. invalid JSON string) inside this hook method. Are there any ways to get and log the body string in case of a bad request?

Note that I'm using Play Framework 2.3 with Scala 2.11.

Comment: Play doesn't allow that " The onBadRequest operation will be called if a route was found, but it was not possible to bind the request parameters:" https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal

Comment: Is there a way other than extending GlobalSettings? For example, is it possible to catch the raw request object before it passed to the global handlers?

Comment: Global.java already extending the GlobalSettings, unfortunately play dosen't provide hook for this.